# CSS class based on the name

Tags: html, css, angular

In my *.css* file I have multiple classes representing my webpage's icon. Based on what I retrieve from my code I want to change the icon.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of parameterStruct">
   <span class="m-menu__link-wrap">
     <i class="sidebar-icon HERE"></i>
       <span class="m-menu__link-text icon-padding sideBar-text"
          style="padding-left: 15px; font-size: 12px"> 
           {{ item.description |translate }}
        </span>
   </span>
</ng-container>
```

Where I wrote *HERE* (in the *i* element) I want to insert my .css class that is `item.description + '-icon'` (E.g. 'myClass-icon').

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `NgClass` [directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). Something like:

`<i class="sidebar-icon" [ngClass]="{'first-icon': item.description === 'first', 'second-icon': item.description === 'second'}"></i>`

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<i class="sidebar-icon {{item.description}}-icon"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using ngClass

```
<i class="sidebar-icon" [ngClass]="item.description?item.description + '-icon': ''"></i>
```